# Unable to override the `onChange` handler of formik Select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

I'm implementing a form in react with the help of Formik and yup. I have Select control form selecting some types here is the code.

Component definition

```js
const MySelect = ({label, ...props}) => {

  const [field, meta] = useField(props)

  return (
      <div>
        <label htmlFor={props.id || props.name}>{label}</label>
        <select 
          {...props} 
          {...field}
        />
        {meta.touched && meta.error ? <div className="error">{meta.error}</div> : null}
      </div>
  )
}
```

Here I'm using it

```js
<MySelect label="Job Type" name="jobType">
    <option value="">Select a job type</option>
    <option value="designer">Designer</option>
    <option value="development">Developer</option>
    <option value="product">Product Manager</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
</MySelect>
```

Till here all works fine but if tried to add a custom `onChange` handler like this:

```js
const MySelect = ({label, ...props}) => {
...
    <select 
      {...props} 
      {...field} 
      onChange={(e) => {
        console.log('Value', e.target.value);
      }
    />
...
}
```

The custom functionality works ok, like in the above case it logs the newly selected value but it disabled the built-in changeHandler, due to which I'm unable to see the newly selected value on the control. Control still showing the first/initial value.

Now my question is how I can merge both (i.e. built-in handler and my custom handler) into 1 handler?

Answer (score 1):

you can use setFieldValue method of Formik

```js
<Field name="jobType">
  {({ field, form: { setFieldValue } }) => (
    <select 
       {...props} 
       {...field} 
       style={ meta.touched && meta.error ? inputErrorStyle : {} }
       onChange={(e) => {
        console.log('Value', e.target.value);
        setFieldValue('jobType', e.target.value)
       }
    />
  )}
</Field>
```

Comment: thanks Amit for your input. But if you can see my `changeHandler` function is outside of the `Formik` I can't get `setFieldValue` there.

Comment: you can pass `setFieldValue` to `changeHandler` and do `setFieldValue('jobType', value)` there

Comment: where from should I pass `setFieldValy` to 'changeHandler' ?